# Should blog results be included in the search results?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm pretty religious about searching for questions, but every once in a while I realise that something I'm looking for is already covered in a related blog.

Would it be beneficial or possible to include Info Sec blog entries with the search results?

Comment: I like this idea. It also helps cover off some of those areas where an SE Q&A doesn't quite work, but the community has provided good content.

Comment: Searching for questions is a religion I can wholeheartedly get behind! And this is an interesting proposal, though I'm religiously ambivalent about it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I'm sure there are some people who don't believe this question exists.

Comment: Well, where is the eviden... oh, wait...

Answer (score 3):

On the Security Stack Exchange, as with many others, we are quite focused on keeping questions and answers within the usual SE guidelines:

- specific answers to focused questions

Our successful blog is actually a very good place for questions that don't fit into that well-structured model, or even for discussions or hypothetical viewpoints, and while we do try and link blog posts to questions where possible (especially for our Question of the Week blog posts) sometimes it would be incredibly useful to provide a visitor to the site searching for information with results that include questions and answers from the site, but also the wider content from the blog.

**tl;dr** - I think it would be incredibly beneficial. Please do this. Kthxbye.